# Upgrading from AngularJS 1.3.0 RC4 to 1.3.0 gives errors

Tags: angularjs

When I change the version of AngularJS from 1.3.0-rc.4 to 1.3.0, I get these errors in the console. I know the stacktrace is not very help because the libraries are concatenated, but the issue seems to occur in angular.js itself.

Any clues please?

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://localhost:3000/index/vendorBundle.js:36891:34
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/index/vendorBundle.js:11114:20)
    at resolveElementClasses (http://localhost:3000/index/vendorBundle.js:36890:9)
    at http://localhost:3000/index/vendorBundle.js:37416:27
    at http://localhost:3000/index/vendorBundle.js:36857:22
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:3000/index/vendorBundle.js:24762:36)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/index/vendorBundle.js:24974:24)
    at bootstrapApply (http://localhost:3000/index/vendorBundle.js:12227:15)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/index/vendorBundle.js:14891:17)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:3000/index/vendorBundle.js:12225:14)
```

Comment: would you mind setting up a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) with an example of a this crashing with one version and working with the other? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular-animate had not been updated to 1.3.0. It was still on 1.3.0-rc.4, which caused this issue.